# Facing issues while producing json response by issuing post requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I would like to get all the school links from the table under `Directory of charter schools in Ohio` across all the next pages from this [website](https://www.causeiq.com/directory/charter-schools-list/ohio-state/) using requests module. To access the school links from next pages, it is necessary to issue post requests with json params. However, I can only access the links of the first page using get requests.

When I attempt to go for post requests, I always get `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:` probably because I didn't include (couldn't find it's whereabouts) `csrftoken` both in headers and cookies.

This is how I've tried:

```
import requests

link = "https://www.causeiq.com/directory/charter-schools-list/ohio-state/"

headers = {
    'referer': 'https://www.causeiq.com/directory/charter-schools-list/ohio-state/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
params = {"filters":[],"pageNumber":"0","sortHow":"popularity","sortDir":"desc"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    resp = s.post(link,json=params)
    print(resp.json())
```

How can I produce json response containing school links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get first 50 items you can use following example (to get more results the page suggests to use [*Cause IQ search interface*](https://www.causeiq.com/search/organizations/o_52cbbe42053d730c/?view=list)):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


link = "https://www.causeiq.com/directory/charter-schools-list/ohio-state/"

headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.causeiq.com/directory/charter-schools-list/ohio-state/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Origin": "https://www.causeiq.com",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
params = {
    "filters": [],
    "pageNumber": "0",
    "sortHow": "popularity",
    "sortDir": "desc",
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    # load cookies
    s.get(link)

    # load csrftoken token
    s.get(link, headers=headers)

    headers["X-CSRFToken"] = s.cookies["csrftoken"]

    orgs = []
    for params["pageNumber"] in range(0, 5):
        data = s.post(link, json=params, headers=headers).json()
        orgs.extend(data["orgs"])


df = pd.DataFrame(orgs)
print(df.head(3).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| url | name | fancy_ein | description | id | det_name | det_secondary_name | det_abbreviation | det_description | det_type | det_meta_prioritygroups | rev_total | det_employees | ass_total | det_ntee | det_primary_address | det_year_formed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /organizations/e-prep-and-village-prep,262367774/ | E Prep and Village Prep | 26-2367774 | E Prep & Village Prep Cliffs Campus serves students in grades K-8, and welcomes students entering at any grade or ability level. The Prep Schools mission is to seek to provide a high quality, academically rigorous education for the college bound scholar. | 262367774 | E Prep and Village Prep |  |  | E Prep & Village Prep Cliffs Campus serves students in grades K-8, and welcomes students entering at any grade or ability level. The Prep Schools mission is to seek to provide a high quality, academically rigorous education for the college bound scholar. | 501(c)(3) | ['PRIORITY_4'] | {'one_year_growth': 68.02840839287008, 'year': '2019', 'value': 8657531, 'series': {'2009': 2345208, '2019': 8657531, '2018': 5152421, '2017': 4941446, '2016': 5178179, '2015': 5335043, '2014': 5052185, '2013': 3763971, '2012': 3724549, '2011': 2623930, '2010': 2123260}} | {'one_year_growth': 61.904761904761905, 'year': '2019', 'value': 102, 'series': {'2019': 102, '2018': 63, '2017': 65, '2016': 73, '2015': 75, '2014': 111, '2013': 81, '2012': 59, '2011': 24, '2010': 24}} | {'one_year_growth': 112.10802607191872, 'year': '2019', 'value': 7795759, 'series': {'2009': 1883847, '2019': 7795759, '2018': 3675372, '2017': 3347101, '2016': 3102715, '2015': 2516026, '2014': 1545238, '2013': 1323677, '2012': 1797580, '2011': 1520817, '2010': 1441603}} | B29 | {'zip': '44114', 'city': 'Cleveland', 'phone': '(216) 456-2070', 'metro': '17460', 'street1': '1415 E 36th St', 'street2': None, 'state': 'OH', 'email': ''} | 2008 |
| /organizations/horizon-science-academy-of-lorain,264574311/ | Horizon Science Academy of Lorain | 26-4574311 | Horizon Science Academy of Lorain is public charter school that serving grades K through 12 for children in Cleveland, OH. The school is a college prep school focusing on math, science and technology education. | 264574311 | Horizon Science Academy of Lorain | BECKY M SCHEIMAN |  | Horizon Science Academy of Lorain is public charter school that serving grades K through 12 for children in Cleveland, OH. The school is a college prep school focusing on math, science and technology education. | 501(c)(3) | ['PRIORITY_4'] | {'one_year_growth': 4.405666781096662, 'year': '2019', 'value': 7779711, 'series': {'2009': 1276506, '2019': 7779711, '2018': 7451426, '2016': 6766792, '2015': 6322058, '2014': 5848132, '2013': 5728648, '2012': 3824747, '2011': 3283336, '2010': 1933082}} | {'one_year_growth': -9.259259259259256, 'year': '2019', 'value': 98, 'series': {'2009': 18, '2019': 98, '2018': 108, '2016': 95, '2015': 102, '2014': 86, '2013': 74, '2011': 43, '2010': 43}} | {'one_year_growth': 18.03196205490267, 'year': '2019', 'value': 4961529, 'series': {'2009': 152995, '2019': 4961529, '2018': 4203547, '2016': 3266537, '2015': 2040844, '2014': 1026625, '2013': 1025081, '2012': 492032, '2011': 506514}} | B29 | {'zip': '44052', 'city': 'Lorain', 'metro': '17460', 'street1': '760 Tower Blvd', 'street2': None, 'state': 'OH'} | 2009 |
| /organizations/breakthrough-charter-schools,270362848/ | Breakthrough Charter Schools | 27-0362848 | Bcs' mission is to provide sustainable, high-quality public Schools in cleveland's under-served neighborhoods, ensuring all students have access to a public, free, outstanding college preparatory education. Our Schools have been honored by local, state,... | 270362848 | Breakthrough Charter Schools |  |  | Bcs' mission is to provide sustainable, high-quality public Schools in cleveland's under-served neighborhoods, ensuring all students have access to a public, free, outstanding college preparatory education. Our Schools have been honored by local, state,... | 501(c)(3) | ['PRIORITY_4'] | {'one_year_growth': -28.839613493997206, 'year': '2018', 'value': 6374546, 'series': {'2018': 6374546, '2017': 8957998, '2016': 8603837, '2015': 8390198, '2014': 5450157, '2013': 4680359, '2012': 5001355, '2011': 2887621}} | {'one_year_growth': -4.81927710843374, 'year': '2018', 'value': 79, 'series': {'2018': 79, '2017': 83, '2016': 80, '2015': 53, '2014': 43, '2013': 35, '2012': 34, '2011': 34}} | {'one_year_growth': -44.85996246242701, 'year': '2018', 'value': 817606, 'series': {'2018': 817606, '2017': 1482781, '2016': 2247379, '2015': 2214294, '2014': 1894363, '2013': 1502679, '2012': 1587906, '2011': 449131}} | B29 | {'zip': '44114', 'city': 'Cleveland', 'metro': '17460', 'street1': '3615 Superior Ave Bldg 44 Ste 4403a', 'street2': '', 'state': 'OH'} | 2009 |

Comment: That was really quick! Thanks a lot Andrej.

Answer (score 0):

First print out resp.text and look at what payload you actually received from the server. (TIP: Yes, you need a csrftoken). You can find your csrftoken in browser devtools, but I don't know if you can use the one from the browser or if you have to generate one yourself. Maybe the [wikipedia page about csrf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) can tell you how csrf is implemented and how to use the token. Secondly, you need to declare that you want to receive JSON data by using "application\json" as content-type in your request headers. I assume the website uses Next.js and you may be able to access the JSON data from the Server-Side Render this way (from what I can tell by the devtools traffic).